# non discrete valuation ring

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, characteristic-p

Hi, 
I am looking for examples of non-discrete valuation rings. Could you help me?
Thanks

Comment: Please read the FAQ; this question does not seem to be appropriate for MO. Anyway I give you a hint: Open a book which treats valuation rings, there are many examples.

Comment: Here is a good example: Let $k$ be a field and consider the field of formal power series $\sum_{i \in I} a_i t^i$ where $I$ can be any well-ordered http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well_ordered subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Sum and product are defined formally by $\sum (a_i+b_i) t^i$ and $\sum a_i b_j t^{i+j}$. Exercise: The sum or product of two formal power series of this form is another one, and every coefficient of the sum or product is a finite polynomial in the coefficents of the summands/multiplicands. The valuation is $v(\sum a_i t^i) = \min(i : a_i \neq 0)$. 

Answer (score 2):

I suggest having a look to Bosch, Güntze and Remmert's "Non-archimedean analysis: a systematic approach to rigid analytic geometry" (1984)

They cover quite a lot of things about valuations and norms.

Answer (score 1):

Take any valuation ring, which is not noetherian.